# Error while converting multiple layers (FeatureServer) to one GeoPackage

Tags: ogr2ogr, geopackage, feature-service

when I want to convert this FeatureServer as one GeoPackage using ogr2ogr on macOS, an error occurred with these messages

> Warning 6: driver ESRIJSON does not support open option NATIVE_DATA
> ERROR 1: Invalid FeatureCollection object. Missing 'fields' member.
> ERROR 1: Layer schema generation failed.
> ERROR 4: Failed to read ESRIJSON data

the full ogr2ogr command :

```
ogr2ogr  -f  GPKG -skipfailures   floridaData.gpkg    "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/ArcGIS/rest/services/COVID19Surge_Florida_InterventionScenarios/FeatureServer/query?layerDefs=%7B%220%22%3A%22OBJECTID+%3C1000%22%2C%221%22%3A%22OBJECTID+%3C1000%22%7D&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outSR=4362&returnGeometry=true&sqlFormat=standard&f=json&maxRecordCountFactor=30&outFields=*&returnExceededLimitFeatures=false&resultType=tile"
```

I don't know why it's not working, the link is working perfectly.

Comment: That isn't a WFS endpoint

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ESRIJSON driver that is responsible for FeatureServer does not support handling multiple layers at the same time, you have to query layer per layer.

For example:

```
ogr2ogr -skipfailures  -f  GPKG floridaData.gpkg "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/ArcGIS/rest/services/COVID19Surge_Florida_InterventionScenarios/FeatureServer/0/query?where=OBJECTID+%3C1000&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outSR=4362&returnGeometry=true&sqlFormat=standard&f=json&maxRecordCountFactor=30&outFields=*&returnExceededLimitFeatures=false&resultType=tile" -nln 0
ogr2ogr -skipfailures -update floridaData.gpkg "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/ArcGIS/rest/services/COVID19Surge_Florida_InterventionScenarios/FeatureServer/1/query?where=OBJECTID+%3C1000&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outSR=4362&returnGeometry=true&sqlFormat=standard&f=json&maxRecordCountFactor=30&outFields=*&returnExceededLimitFeatures=false&resultType=tile" -nln 1
```

[For more info](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/4613#issuecomment-937529710)